# How to pass in log file creation to pass in to script to attach the file

Tags: linux, bash, cron, parameter

I have several cron jobs I run to back up dbs:

```
0 8 * * * BACKUP=DEV DB=01 /usr/local/bin/backup.sh > /var/log/backup-db01-`date "+\%m\%d\%y"`.log 2>&1||/usr/local/bin/create-ticket.sh

0 16 * * * BACKUP=DEV DB=02 /usr/local/bin/backup.sh > /var/log/backup-db02-`date "+\%m\%d\%y"`.log 2>&1||/usr/local/bin/create-ticket.sh
```

In the script I am trying to create JIRA ticket on failure and attach the logs for the backup:

*create-ticket.sh* script:

```
#create Ticket for failed backup#
JIRA=`/opt/atlassian-cli/jira.sh --server https://blahblah --user admin --password blahblah --action createIssue --project "DEV" --type "Incident" --summary "Failed backup on $BACKUP $DB" --components "blah" --priority "Major"| awk '{print $2}'`

###Atttach logs:###
/opt/atlassian-cli/jira.sh --server https://blahblah --user admin --password blahblah --action addAttachment --issue "${JIRA}" --file "?????"
```

I need to know how to pass in the different file names for each time the cron runs to the {`--file "???"`} section... the file name changes daily and i need the script to pick up the newly created file for each DB on each day it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper script to clean up your crontab;

```
0 8 * * * /usr/local/bin/backupOrTicket.sh 01
```

and put this in it;

```
DB=$1
BACKUP=DEV
FILE="/var/log/backup-$DB-$(date +%m%d%y).log"
/usr/local/bin/backup.sh > "$FILE" 2>&1 \
|| /usr/local/bin/create-ticket.sh "$FILE"
```

Using `--file "$1"` in create-ticket.sh . You might want to remove the BACKUP variable if it's not actually used. Also you should use `date --iso-8601=s` so that your log files sort properly. (Using any date format other than numerical largest to smallest is an [anti pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern))

Answer (score -1):

I think you can introduce log file name parameter to be used for both redirection and when calling create-ticket.sh

```
0 8 * * * BACKUP=DEV DB=01 LOG=/var/log/backup-db01-$(date "+%m%d%y").log /usr/local/bin/backup.sh > $LOG 2>&1 || /usr/local/bin/create-ticket.sh $LOG
```

so create-ticked.sh should be then expecting that parameter and you can use it inside like

```
 ... --file "$1" ...
```

You may not want to use escaping % sign - $(date "+%m%d%y") - part will result in string like 021318 once so you guaranteed to stick with the same name.

Comment: `%` is special in crontabs and _needs_ to be escaped.